# Can I change the behavior of the material design PopupBox in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I'm using WPF with [Material Design](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML) in XAML. My code is pretty simple:

```
<materialDesign:PopupBox Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignMultiFloatingActionAccentPopupBox}"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                         Margin="32">
   <StackPanel>
      <Button x:Name="ImprimirButton" ToolTip="Imprimir">
         <Button.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Light BluePrimary500}" />
         </Button.Background>
         <Button.Foreground>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Light BluePrimary500Foreground}" />
         </Button.Foreground>
         <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Printer" />
      </Button>
   </StackPanel>
</materialDesign:PopupBox>
```

The behavior of this floating `PopupBox` is to show the buttons on mouse hover. I want to change it to show the buttons on mouse click. Is this possible?

When the mouse hovers the top of the floating `PopupBox`, it also triggers the event and shows all the buttons, which is very annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the default behavior of the `MaterialDesignMultiFloatingActionAccentPopupBox` style that defaults the popup mode to `MouseOverEager`. Just set the `PopupMode` to `Click` on your `PopupBox`.

```
<materialDesign:PopupBox Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignMultiFloatingActionAccentPopupBox}"
                         PopupMode="Click"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                         VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                         Margin="32">
   <!-- ...your XAML code. -->
</materialDesign:PopupBox>
```